# Git - what is causing “warning: Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes”

Tags: git, gitolite

When pushing on my server the `post-receive` hook runs a simple `git clone` command.

The command returns the following warning and I don't know what it means or how to resolve it. Googling the error gave only results concerning gitattributes and I haven't configured any attributes. My .gitignore file also has no exclamation marks or negative values inside.

```
remote: Cloning into '/var/www/html/gitrep'...        
remote: warning: Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes
remote: Use '\!' for literal leading exclamation.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

One of your gitattributes file use a negative pattern that is not allowed.
Search for one of those files:

- `.gitattributes` inside any folder of your repository
- `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes`
- `$(git config --get core.attributesFile)`
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes`
- `$HOME/.config/git/attributes`
- `$(prefix)/etc/gitattributes`

One of them use a negative pattern. You just need to fix it (by adapting your gitattributes model or escaping the exclamation point)

Comment: Problem was solved by searching for every `.gitattributes`-file in the git repository.

One of these Files had a row starting with an exclamation mark which wasn't commented out that was causing this warning.

Comment: Found the culprit in my repository with: ```for i in `find . -name ".gitattributes"`; do echo ""; echo "FILE:"; echo $i; cat $i | grep \!; done;``` Note this doesn't take into account all of the other places outside the repository mentioned in the post above!